# Find matching rows across two sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet1 (sh1) where I have a country name in say (A2) and a direction in (B2).

I would like to find a row on sheet2 (sh2) where column A contains the same city name and column B contains the same district and copy that entire row next to the row on sh1 that was matching. Then I would like to loop through all rows on sh1 and find the matching rows on sh2 and copy it in the same manner.

It might seem I am duplicating data, but the matched row on sh2 contains other information I'd like to copy to sh1.

To illustrate:

> ```
> On Sheet1:
>
> Column A               Column B
> (header)               (header)
> San Diego              South
> New York               North
> Chicago                East
>
> On Sheet2:
>
> Column A              Column B
> (header)              (header)
> Chicago               East              
> San Diego             South
> New York              North
> ```

The loop would first check for San Diego, then New York, then Chicago and so on until the end of the column.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Matchcountry()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    r = lastrow = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count) + 2.End(xlUp).Row    

    For x = 1 To r    
        If sh1.Range("A" & x) = sh2.Range("A" & x) And sh1.Range("B" & x) = sh1.Range("A" & x) & sh2.Range("B" & x) Then 
            sh1.Range("A" & x).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sh2.Range("C" & x)    
        x = x + 1    
    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already pretty close, try this corrected code (corrections are in comments):

```
Sub Matchcountry()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim r As Long, r2 As Long 'we just need the row number, not the Range object

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
r = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'All the necessary parts were there, just the syntax was wrong
r2 = sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim x As Long, y As Long 'It's good practice to declare all your variables
For x = 1 To r
    For y = 1 To r2
        If sh1.Cells(x, 1).Value2 = sh2.Cells(y, 1).Value2 And sh1.Cells(x, 2).Value2 = sh2.Cells(y, 2).Value2 Then 'Again, most necessary parts were already there
            sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(x, 1), sh1.Cells(x, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy Destination:=sh2.Range("C" & y) 'We don't need the entire row, in fact we won't be able to copy it to the desired renage since it's too big
            Exit For 'will stop the second loop once it's found a match
        End If
    Next y
    'x = x + 1 Common mistake. Next x already iterates x, by doing it this way we skip every second step
Next x

End Sub
```

The biggest change is the second `For` loop. We need the second loop since you you want to loop through `sh2` for **every** row of `sh1`, nut just once.

Comment: Modify `Destination:=sh2.Range("C" & x)` to `sh2.Rows(x)`, he asked for whole row (additional data) :)

Comment: Both approaches work. You could copy the entire row and paste it into the first column or just copy the subset of data that i dfferent beginning in the third column and paste it into the third column. But you cannot paste the entire row to column `C` since it will not fit.

Comment: In case `sh1.Range("A" & x).EntireRow.Copy sh2.Range("C" & x)` that line is not working, because of different size ( I assume that in one sheet he has more data than in second one).

Comment: I just noticed I forgot to delete the `.EntireRow` in my code, that was not supposed to be there. That line you mentioned does not work because it is copying a range with `Rows.Count` number of rows and is trying to paste it to a range with `Rows.Count - 2` number of rows. The copied range does not fit into the destination range.

Comment: I know that 'why', I just wanted to adjust code to `.EntireRow`, that's all :) But now You figured out that it is not needed, edited and everything is fine now :)

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting Error 1004 on this line: sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(x, 1), sh1.Cells(x, Rows.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy Destination:=sh2.Range("C" & x)

Comment: @Rhyfelwr Sorry, it should have been `Columns.Count`. I corrected the code above, please copy the entire code and try again.